# Android ViewGroup fade only content/children not background

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a simple way to just set the transparency of the content (children) of a `ViewGroup`?

Background: I got a custom `FrameLayout` with a bunch of different views in it. Now I want to fade out only the content/children:

- The `backgroundColor` of the layout should always be visible - so I cannot just `setAlpha()` on the whole `ViewGroup`
- I do not want to loop through all the children and call `child.setAlpha()` on every one of them manually

**Current Approach**

*It's working but I'm not completely satisfied with it - I think there is a simpler solution.*

Override `dispatchDraw()` and just draw a rectangle above all content:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

    // Draw the alpha overlay above the children.
    if (mGridAlpha < 1.0f) {
        mOverlayPaint.setColor(adjustAlpha(mOverlayPaint.getColor(), 1 - mGridAlpha));
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), mOverlayPaint);
    }
}

public static int adjustAlpha(int color, float factor) {
    int alpha = Math.round(255 * factor);
    int red = Color.red(color);
    int green = Color.green(color);
    int blue = Color.blue(color);
    return Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
}
```

Fading in/out is done manually with a `ValueAnimator`:

```
public void fadeContent(final boolean in) {
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            mGridAlpha = in ? fraction : 1 - fraction;
            // Key here is to call invalidate() which will cause a dispatchDraw() call
            invalidate();
        }
    });
    animator.start();
}
```